# Scrollbar passing screen limit

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a layout using Bootstrap, but I'm having problems in the layout.

My site will be based on tabs, but am having trouble leaving the part that has the scrollbar with the height of ownership: 100%, and is passing the screen limits.

Could someone help me what I'm missing?
I left the project in jsFiddle. Note the scrollbar that is passing the screen limit ..

```
Link
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e5bLr5xd/1/

Answer (score 0):

Changing the height of your `content` element to a value less than 100% prevented the scrollbar from passing the screen limit, but it wasn't always perfectly aligned with the bottom of the page at different window sizes.

So, I added some simple jQuery statements to adjust the height of `content` based on the height of the `left-side` navigation element, minus an offset value.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.content').height($('.left-side').height()-160);
});

$( window ).resize(function() {
    $('.content').height($('.left-side').height()-160);
});
```

With these functions, the height of `content` is first set when the page is loaded, and then again whenever the window is resized. The bottom of the scrollbar is always perfectly matched with the bottom of the page.

You can see a working revision of your fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/e5bLr5xd/4/

I hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me.